# How to say "including"

Tags: words

I want to say "During my gap year, I want to learn about severals countries, including Japan."
ギャップイヤーの間にたくさんの国について学びたいです。(including Japan)

Answer (score 5):

Most commonly and naturally, one would say:

> 「日本{にほん}を**含{ふく}む**多{おお}くの国{くに}」

That is:

> 「X +を + 含む + 多くの + Y」
>
> = "many Y's including X"